# Ошибка вывода значения из checkbox

Tags: jquery, javascript

Из-за чего не выводит значение инпута?

```
alert($("input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что у чекбокса не атрибут, а свойство. правильно делать так:

(начиная с jQuery 1.6)

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

На любителя, я делаю вот так:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')  // true или false
```

Comment: Я знаю, что так работает, но не могу понять почему так как я делаю не работает?!